# Are there benefits to keep pursuing ranks in different vocations?

Tags: dragons-dogma

My character is a lvl 10 Fighter, lvl 10 Assassin & lvl 8 Mystic Knight. I've just switched vocation whenever I've hit lvl 10 as to not "waste" any "vocation XP". Next I'm switching to Magic Archer.

Are there any benefits (except the obvious of having the choice of different high level vocations) to doing it this way compared to just sticking with a vocation? Each switch makes me vulnerable (as I'm lvl 1 again) so there's an obvious disadvantage right there.

Comment: Realized this is a duplicate. I vote to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is that you can mix the Augments: although the unlocking of augments is locked to a vocation, after unlocking, you can use them in your character regardless of the vocation. Then you can do some nice mix-ups

[Check here](http://dragonsdogma.wikia.com/wiki/Augments)